# ¿Cómo puedo detectar la colisión?

Tags: javascript, html5, motor-de-juego

Me gustaría que me ayudaseis a detectar la colisión de la pelota con la plataforma en javascript, me está matando.
Gracias.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(evento) {
if (evento.keyCode==39) {
 if (plataforma.x<550) {
  plataforma.x+=10;
 }

} 
if (evento.keyCode==37) {
 if (plataforma.x>0) {
  plataforma.x-=10;
 }

}
});

var canvas, ctx;
function inicializar() {
 canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
 ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
}
var plataforma={x:250, y:280};
function dibujaPlataforma(){
 ctx.fillRect(plataforma.x,plataforma.y,150,20);
}

var ancho=700;
var alto=300;
function borrarCanvas(){
canvas.width=ancho;
canvas.height=alto;
}

var bola={x:20, y:50, xmax:700, ymax:300, xdir:'left', ydir:'down', ancho:10, velocidad:5};

function dibujaPelota(){
 ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(bola.x,bola.y,bola.ancho,0,2*Math.PI);
 ctx.fill();
}

function pelotaRebotando() {
 if (bola.xdir=='right') {
  if (bola.x>(bola.xmax-bola.ancho-bola.velocidad)) {
   bola.xdir='left';
  }
 }else{
  if (bola.xdir=='left') {
   if (bola.x<(0+bola.ancho+bola.velocidad)) {
    bola.xdir='right';
   }
  }
 }
 if (bola.ydir=='down') {
  if (bola.y>(bola.ymax-bola.ancho-bola.velocidad)) {
   bola.ydir='up';
  }
 }else{
  if (bola.ydir=='up') {
   if (bola.y<(0+bola.ancho+bola.velocidad)) {
    bola.ydir='down';
   }
  }
  
 }
 //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 if (bola.xdir=='right') {
  bola.x+=bola.velocidad;
 }
 if (bola.xdir=='left') {
  bola.x-=bola.velocidad;
 }
 if (bola.ydir=='up') {
  bola.y-=bola.velocidad;
 }
 if (bola.ydir=='down') {
  bola.y+=bola.velocidad;
 }

}


//Bucle principal
setInterval(function () {
 borrarCanvas();
 dibujaPlataforma();
 dibujaPelota();
 pelotaRebotando();//Lógica Pelota
},50);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Pelota</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="inicializar();">
<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="300" style="border-style: solid;">
 <p>Tu navegador no es compatible con este programa, busca una versión más reciente</p>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, creo que vas a tener que ser mas especifico sobre el problema. Es que no colisionan, o se detectan incorrectamente? o que ocurre?

Comment: Ya está solucionado chicos, gracias por vuestro interés, lo que quería era programar la colisión.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando la direccion de la pelota sea hacia abajo es donde tienes que checar la colicion viendo que la altura de la pelota (Y) sea la misma o mayor que la de la barra y la posicion del eje X de la pelota sea mayor igual a la de la barra y menor que el eje X de la barra mas su ancho

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(evento) {
if (evento.keyCode==39) {
 if (plataforma.x<550) {
  plataforma.x+=10;
 }

} 
if (evento.keyCode==37) {
 if (plataforma.x>0) {
  plataforma.x-=10;
 }

}
});

var canvas, ctx;
function inicializar() {
 canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
 ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
}
var plataforma={x:250, y:280};
function dibujaPlataforma(){
 ctx.fillRect(plataforma.x,plataforma.y,150,20);
}

var ancho=700;
var alto=300;
function borrarCanvas(){
canvas.width=ancho;
canvas.height=alto;
}

var bola={x:20, y:50, xmax:700, ymax:300, xdir:'left', ydir:'down', ancho:10, velocidad:5};

function dibujaPelota(){
 ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(bola.x,bola.y,bola.ancho,0,2*Math.PI);
 ctx.fill();
}

function pelotaRebotando() {
 if (bola.xdir=='right') {
  if (bola.x>(bola.xmax-bola.ancho-bola.velocidad)) {
   bola.xdir='left';
  }
 }else{
  if (bola.xdir=='left') {
   if (bola.x<(0+bola.ancho+bola.velocidad)) {
    bola.xdir='right';
   }
  }
 }
 if (bola.ydir=='down') {
    //Solo para diferenciar que choco contra el borde
    if (bola.y>(bola.ymax-bola.ancho-bola.velocidad))
      console.log("perdiste");
    //---------
    
  if (bola.y>(bola.ymax-bola.ancho-bola.velocidad)  ||
         //En esta parte de la condicion checamos la colicion
        (
         //La pelota debe de estar a la misa altura o mayor a la barra
         bola.y >= plataforma.y &&
         //La pos X de la pelota debe de ser mayor o igual a la Pos X de la barra
         bola.x >= plataforma.x &&
         //Pero tambien la pos X de la pelota tiene que ser menor a la posicion X de la barra mas su ancho
         bola.x <= plataforma.x + 150
        ) 
    ) {
   bola.ydir='up';
  }
 }else{
  if (bola.ydir=='up') {
   if (bola.y<(0+bola.ancho+bola.velocidad)) {
    bola.ydir='down';
   }
  }
  
 }
 //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 if (bola.xdir=='right') {
  bola.x+=bola.velocidad;
 }
 if (bola.xdir=='left') {
  bola.x-=bola.velocidad;
 }
 if (bola.ydir=='up') {
  bola.y-=bola.velocidad;
 }
 if (bola.ydir=='down') {
  bola.y+=bola.velocidad;
 }

}


//Bucle principal
setInterval(function () {
 borrarCanvas();
 dibujaPlataforma();
 dibujaPelota();
 pelotaRebotando();//Lógica Pelota
},50);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Pelota</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="inicializar();">
<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="300" style="border-style: solid;">
 <p>Tu navegador no es compatible con este programa, busca una versión más reciente</p>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Te dejo un [link](https://helmetwarsgame.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/funcion-de-deteccion-de-colision-entre-dos-rectangulos-de-un-plano/) donde explican un poco mas el algoritmo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, aunque lo descubrí unos minutos antes de ver tu respuesta.